# Bittorrent Sync Autostart as a Service

Tags: services, raspberry-pi, bittorrent, init.d

I'm running a raspberry pi with the latest raspbian (debian) on it.

I've installed btsync. Now I want to run Bittorrent Sync, when the system boots, not only when somebody logs in.

Do I have to run btsync as a service in init.d?

How would you solve this "Problem"?

Comment: search "write a system v init script" on google. I'd give you a real answer but I only have experience with systemd.

Comment: You can use /etc/rc.local as well .

Comment: what if I want to start the programm as root? (unfortunately it can't be run as pi (normal user))

Comment: it will start as root automatically if you use `init.d` or `rc.local`.

Comment: Set up AUTOSTART in `/etc/default/btsync`, then it'll start automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a post with this topic was just released on the bittorrent blog:

http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/09/17/sync-hacks-how-to-set-up-bittorrent-sync-on-ubuntu-server-13-04/